# ENOENT localhost:3306 error

Tags: mysql, node.js

When I run my code Developed using nodejs express and mysql, I sometimes get error name ENOENT localhost:3306. Please some one t
Help me why I get this error. I don't get it all the time. But sometime. And I get when I am connected with my local mysql server.

Comment: What did Google tell you?

Comment: did you start mysql server  .?

Comment: can you show more error log ? My guess is the limited connections to mysql

Answer (score 9):

If your mysql connection string has defined  `"localhost"` then tried to using `"127.0.0.1"` , hope it works ...

Comment: Works for me in my case when i was connected to internet mysql was connecting successfully but when i disconnect the internet it shows the error then i replace **localhost** with 127.0.0.1